# Booklet print, every physical sheet (not page) is stacked upside down

Tags: printing, acrobat-pro-dc

We have recently updated our printer to an HP M880, with a stacker/stapler addition.

I'm able to print booklets without folding or stapleing just fine, however when I turn on the feature "fold and stitch" the pages become muddled and the whole booklet gets printed.... "inside out".

This is difficult to explain so to i'll try to be clear.

The physical 4 page sheets, that create the saddle stitch pages are all stacked upside down.

The pages on the sheets are all the same way round wihin the booklet. The individual 4 page sheets are also in the correct order. However each A4 piece of paper is stacked upside down.

This results with the cover being the 2nd page, 2nd page being the cover, the third page is the 4th and the 4th the 3rd... etc. All the way round and back to the first sheet, where the last page is the 2nd last and the second last page is the back cover...

When looking at it "opened up" so you should see the front cover and the back cover, what I actually see are pages 2 and the 2nd last page. (the covers are on the other side of this sheet of paper)

The pages are there for layed out as:
2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9,12,11...etc

I've attempted the following (not limited to):

- Reverse page order, this just makes it so that the same incorrect page stacking happens so that the cover and back cover are the middle and 2nd from the middle of the booklet.
- flip/turn options
- portrait/landscape options (this turned the other side of the sheet upside down or right way round) ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
- and a miriad number of different combinations of these three and others...

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

My experience was similar the other day: Using the settings in the Acrobat dialogue; The pages on the "backside" of the sheets making up the booklet were printed with the content upside down, regardless of setting combination.

My analysis ended up with: Adobe Acrobat seems to have a problem with booklet printing currently (Note: not entirely verified).

Fix: Make Acrobat print the pages as if on single sided single sheet per page ("normal" or "basic", can't remember the term they use for it).

Then adjust the parameters for the printer DRIVER <kbd>Properties</kbd> to get the Booklet.

*The other alternative is to make Acrobat create the booklet pages, and then staple them yourself. Unless you can find settings that makes the printer do it. And here you have better set the printer driver to a "basic" settings first.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However this is not my issue.

The contents on each page are the correct way round. The actual physical pages, the paper it's self is stacked so that each sheet of paper is physically upside down. Flipped over so that the pages are in the wrong order. 

When looking at it "opened up" so you should see the front cover and tha back cover, what I see are pages 2 and the 2nd last page. (the covers are on the other side of this sheet of paper)

Comment: continued: 

Under this sheet is the sheet for pages 3, 4 and the 3rd last and 4th last page... this sheet also is flipped... so the pages in the whole booklet go in the following order:

2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9... etc.

Comment: I still do believe the problem is similar, the "classic" is where you get a mix of the required operations (page flipping and ordering) applied of TWO software entities - by that creating the mess. But for now; check whether you have reverse order printing active.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original, I've tested it with both reversed page order and not reversed. The difference was that the cover moved from the outside fold to the inside fold of the booklet. 
The pages were still "flipped".

Comment: As an added note: Your FIX is precisely how we have had to do it for the time. 
By leaveing the Adobe settings to hte most basic and making changes in the printer driver properties. We can then print it in booklet form (only folded). The issue arrises when we attempt to include the staples in the printing process, ie. picking the fold-and-stitch setting.